# Clip/ Limit Geom_Line plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, clipping

I'd like to make a line plot where I need to clip some lines below/above certain y values. As an example

```
  x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    y1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    y2 <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20)
    df <- data_frame(x, y1, y2)

    #make plot for df
    ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, group=1)) +

#plot y=x
    geom_line(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y1, colour="red"))+

#plot y=2x for values of y equal to/ above 3
    geom_line(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y2 >=3, colour="blue"))
```

obviously this doesn't work but is it possible? And if so, how? The obvious solution would be to edit the data frame itself but for my final goal this won't work. Another solution would be to make the plot invisible (in this case) above y=3 but was unsure if thats possible either

Apologies if it's been asked before. I tried searching around but didn't find anything. Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to make a factor of your condition and use that to color the line:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y2, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(y2 >= 3)))
```

which gives:

[image]

---

Upon re-reading your question, I think I might have misinterpreted it. Slightly adapting your code to only include the values equal to or above 3:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y1)) +
  geom_line(colour="red")+
  geom_line(data=df[df$y2 >= 3,], aes(x=x, y=y2), colour="blue")
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: ahhh there is a simple solution all along :) Thanks- looks like that should work perfectly for what I want (and the first part is also useful to have :D )

Comment: ahhh, this actually doesn't quite do what I wanted and I didn't realsie until now. Is it possible to draw the line of y=2x from y=3 upwards without having the value for x=1.5, y=3.

i.e. to draw the line as normal and introduce a high pass filter afterwards for y=3

Comment: @RobertHickman To which part of the answer are you referring? And what do you mean by *"high pass filter"*? Please explain more clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry for the poor explaining. What I'm trying to do in the example is plot the line y=2x but then only show the values for y greater than equal to 3 (even if there is no data point at y=3). 

The solution you posted jumps to the next data point (x=2, y=4).

I don't really know how to describe what I want it to do but basically the data would lead to the white line being plotted, whereas I want only the regions in black to show (http://imgur.com/u8KJKQg)